# Potential risks per ISO 27002 clauses 5-18

Tags: risk-analysis, iso27001, iso27002, iso27005

I have a study project related to establishing of ISO 27001.

I will do GAP analyses on "fictional" company over all ISO 27001 Annex A controls using ISO 27002.

After I do that, I will detect the risks using the results of that GAP analyses.

So my question is if there is a list of potential risks per each ISO 27001 Annex A control (or at least per each clause 5-18) ?

Comment: I don't think that you are asking the correct question. A list of risks is endless. What are you doing a gap analysis against? ISO 27002 is one side of the gap, what's the other?

Comment: There are published Risk Catalogues and they can contain thousands of potential risks including version-specific vulnerabilities to "all the IT people quit at the same time". You need to narrow your focus quite a bit.

Comment: @schroeder I have a "fictional" company which I will do the GAP analyses on using ISO 27002.

Comment: ok, then the company details provide the starting place for risks

Answer (score 2):

"Controls", which is what clauses 5-18 are, are meant to mitigate risks. They help to reduce the impact or the likelihood of a risk crystalising to a level that the organisation is comfortable with.

So all those control clauses point to the risks they are meant to mitigate. Just think to yourself, "what would happen if this control was not there or if it failed?". Then you can build a (very) large list of risks that might be relevant to your example.

Answer (score 0):

Risk analysis is done in advance to the ISO 27002 controls implementation.
An ISMS implementation always follows the PDCA - Plan Do Check Act.
Plan means in your case:

- create an inventory of all information assets that this company has
- determine a risk assessment strategy, most common is the 'Impact x Likelihood  = Risk' approach
- **collect a list of threats**
- assess the risks of all assets by determining an impact and likelihood value on it

So the risks are threats to the assets of this 'virtual' company that can happen by a certain likelihood.

What those risks are, depends a lot on the company, but for a start you could look up the corresponding assets in the [IT Grundschutzkompendium](https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Themen/Unternehmen-und-Organisationen/Standards-und-Zertifizierung/IT-Grundschutz/it-grundschutz_node.html)
Example:

Asset: Employee Laptop
Threat: Hardware Defects in Client System
(Taken from SYS.2.1 General Client, Section 2 - Threat landscape)

Impact: 4 (Scale from 1-4, while 4 the highest, entirely your choice)
Likelihood: 4 (happens all the time because your users shower with their equipment)

Risk value: 16

Now you put all of this in an Excel sheet and then sort by risk value. Afterwards you apply the controls of ISO 27002 on it to reduce that risk.

In the example case: User training and awareness (A7.1.2) reduces the likelihood by 2 points.

Comment: The question is asking what risks to identify, not how to assess the identified risks. This answer skips over that entire point.

Comment: good point. WIll extend